# What would you say is the ideal percent of money per check should go into your savings account?

Tags: savings, savings-account

I would typically for me I'd say 12 - 20%. That way even if its a small check due to hours I'll still be able have some cash in hand.

Comment: What is your reason for saving? Retirement, emergencies, to buy/repair stuff?

Comment: Details required as to purpose etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use a rule of thumb for this. Instead, I use a budget.

Throwing money into a savings account for the purpose of building a savings account is okay, but I only put money into a savings account that I have a purpose for.

For example, there are bills that come up once a year, such as insurance premiums, property tax, annual subscriptions and memberships, etc. I plan for these in my budget each month, and the money goes into my savings.

I also have an emergency fund, which is used in the event that a large, one-time, unexpected expense comes up that I hadn't planned for. I have a goal for how large I want this fund to be, so I put money in savings until it is built up to the level I want it at.

There are other long range saving goals I have: my next car, vacation, furniture replacement, technology replacement, etc. Each of these gets some money each month, which goes into savings.

I also have retirement savings in the budget, but that doesn't go into the savings account; it gets invested in my retirement account.

My point is that instead of arbitrarily choosing a percentage of your income to put into a savings account, think about the purpose of that money. That will help you determine how much needs to be saved, and it will also help motivate you to do so.

Comment: And use a spreadsheet to keep track of the e-fund, "deferred spending" and long range saving categories who's money all gets lumped into one (or a few) account(s).